# Is there any way to authenticate users with instagram in my ionic app?

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I want to know if someone could already do something like this, because the new Instagram basic display API is kind of different. Thanks in advance

I've been working in a Ionic 3 app, which authenticated users with Instagram API. But now Instagram API is no longer working, and was migrated to Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new API, Facebook no longer allows users to authenticate into an app using the Instagram Basic Display API, and the Graph API for Businesses and Creators requires a Facebook token.

I suppose they now want you to only use the Facebook auth flow to authenticate your users for your app, and then have them log in again to Instagram for Basic Display after your primary authentication.

> "Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app
>   users or log them into your app. If you need an authentication
>   solution we recommend using Facebook Login instead."
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

&

> "All endpoint requests must include a Facebook User access token."
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview